# Study material for Advanced Databases module inc SQL, Relational Model, ERM & TM

Tags: database-design, transaction, relational-theory

For my next module in my masters, I am planning on studying Advanced Databases. (Long story short, the masters is designed for people with NON-CS degrees, so I have never studied databases, therefore I have literally 0 knowledge).

The lecturer mentioned that I must have an understanding on the following concepts:

1. **The relational Model;**
2. **Relational Algebra (and maybe Relational Calculus);**
3. **SQL;**
4. **Entity-Relationship Modelling (ERM) and Enhanced ERM (we are using UML notations);**
5. **Transactions Management;**

**I'm aware that questions have been asked about study resources on the subjects**, particularly SQL, but, does anyone some good resource that covers a few of the subjects mentioned? Preferably online sources (so they will keep up to date).

Comment: I suggest this one: [Relational Theory for Computer Professionals (Theory in Practice)](http://www.amazon.com/Relational-Theory-Computer-Professionals-Practice/dp/144936943X/)

Comment: @ypercube seems like a very valid choice. The book mentions who its designed for and the author specifically mentions: "I don't assume you know anything about databases, relational or otherwise, nor about SQL in particular". +1 for that!

Comment: Changed the question to make it more suitable to the rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the course at Standford to be helpful - if you sign up, you can view past lectures on many of these topics.

https://class.stanford.edu/courses/Engineering/db/2014_1/info

Comment: This looks very good, in particular [this course](https://class.stanford.edu/courses/DB/2014/SelfPaced/about)

Comment: I've worked my way through this course and I am now 2 months into my Advanced Database module. This was by far the best resource, it massively helped! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Database systems by Connolly and Begg

Comment: this is the actual book that they will use for the module. So I think this assumed prior db knowledge?

Answer (score 0):

Head First SQL was very helpful for me in terms of SQL.

I also found Beginning Database Design From Novice to Professional to be very useful for understanding the Relational Model.

The website [SQL Zoo](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/Main_Page) is also very useful for learning SQL.

To be honest I wouldn't get so many books just on SQL - it isn't *that* hard, and Head First SQL explains it very clearly. I'd say learning SQL is probably the easiest thing from your list :)

Also, you can always sign up to Safari Books Online for a monthly fee rather than buying these books (There are other similar sites but it's the one I'm familiar with). It's a monthly subscription and gives you access to lots of books. Both the books I suggested are on there. I find it pretty helpful for me because it means I can find books which suit my own learning style rather than spending money and finding it doesn't suit me.

Comment: Thanks for the info, the SQL zoo looks very, very useful! I have considered getting Safari Books online, BUT, I look at a monitor for at least 12h a day and it's refreshing using a book :). I think I will order Head First SQL, the java book was very good, so I'm sure I'll get up to speed in no time :)

Comment: Yeah I found it very helpful :) Their style of teaching really suits me a lot of the time